# TensorFlow Loss with multiple simultaneous predictions

Tags: tensorflow, keras

In my model, I am attempting to create a custom loss function which compares 2 predictions.

Each training sample uses 2 predictions and has the following form:

`(x1,x2) -> (y_pred(x1),y_pred(x2))`

`loss = |y_pred1 - y_pred2|`

The point is there is no `y_true` in this case. I am trying to minimize the difference in output between two different inputs.

Superficially, how would I go about implementing such a custom model/loss in TensorFlow?

Implementing this must be more broad than just the loss function. TensorFlow’s loss functions seem to universally compare a prediction with a “ground truth,” so this is a radically different approach in training. Will I have to write an entire custom model with custom training step for this to work? If so, what is the most critical subcomponent from which I extract multiple predictions in the same training step?